# Node.js callback function questions

Tags: node.js, testing, callback, mocha.js, chai

I'm using mocha and the request module for some tests.

Why is this.restresponse = 'test' and never the body json
using the code below. The mocha test calls the function code below and then on the callback checks this.restresponse. It is always 'test' even though the body is passed back in the callback.

```
this.restresponse = 'test';
request(this.formatted, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        this.restresponse = body;
        callback(null, body); // pass back the body
    } else {
        this.restresponse = error;
        callback(error, null); // pass back the error
    }
});
```

Many thanks

Answer (score -1):

Because the request method has no access to the this object. duh!